# download csv from sftp server and use it as data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sftp, rcurl

I would like to download a csv file from sftp server and use it as a data frame.

I'm doing the following:

```
library(RCurl) 


url<-c("sftp://data.ftp.net/data.csv")
x <-getURL(url, userpwd="<username>:<passwd>")
writeLines(x, con="data.csv"))

dataframe <- read.csv("data.csv")
```

The problem is that when using getURL it takes too long to read the file, e.g. ,about 12+ mins to read a 38~mb file, when normally it would take seconds to download the files in other FTP clients such as Filezilla. This is a drastic difference when considering the case of downloading multiple files.

Is there a more efficient/faster way to do this?

Comment: Which part takes the longest? Have you timed each line? Once you have x, there may be no need to write to disc and reload the data. But if it's the ftp step itself that's slow, then there's a different problem.

Comment: The FTP step is the one that is slow.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)